# Find audio sections in MP4s higher than a specified level?

Tags: software, research

I am working on a system to collect data for noise ordinances and need to correlate video with decibel meters (decibel meter, video and sound) are at the same locations.

A vehicle that emits sound levels greater that ambient plus 3 sigma for a given street is considered to be in violation.

Is there software available that can search by audio levels (i.e., jump to the loudest sections of an MP4 for license plates...)

Answer (score 1):

If my memory is good, [Sony - Sound Forge](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/fr/soundforgesoftware) have an Auto Region tool. This could do the trick.

Comment: I think Cubase has a similar function, but neither are very good with the video side of this. (The OP needs to view the frame/s in the MP4 where the peaks occur.) Many audio editors have peak analysis, like Audition. They give the time and level of the highest peak.